# Alternating series error bound: first term of remainder is greater than sum of remaining terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{1/2}}.$$

Let the $S$ denote the above sum of an alternating series. If $S_k$ denotes sum of first $k$ terms and $R_k$ denotes sum of remainder, $R_k$ is supposed to be smaller or equal to the first term of $R_k$, in the equation $S=S_k+R_k$. The given example for this was when $k=4$, where $R_k$ is denoted by $(\text{first term of the remainder})-(\text{sum of the remaining terms})$. Here, the first term will be negative, while sum of the remaining terms will be positive, yielding a result that is certainly smaller or equal to the first term. But I am curious what happens when I choose $k=5$ instead. In that case, the remainder's first term will be negative. Does it lead to the same result as $k=4$ by manipulating the remainder to the same form?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Surely if $k=4,$ then the first term of the remainder is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5} },\ $ which is positive ? But you say, "Here, the first term will be negative." ?